# How to execute this sqlite instruccions from code?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, csv, export

I need to export the information of my database to a csv file. I already know how to do that in sqlite but i need to do it from the code of an ios aplication.

**I have to execute this from code.**

```
.separator ,   
.mode csv  
.output test.csv  
select * from tbl1;  
.output stdout
```

I mean those aren´t instructions like inserts or updates or deletes or selects...(well only one)

I tried something like this:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;  

const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];  
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_bdcontact) == SQLITE_OK) {  
    NSString *querySQLite = @".separator ,";  
    const char *querySQLite_stmt = [querySQLite UTF8String];  
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_bdcontact, querySQLite_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);  
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {  
        NSLog(@"Did what i need and just repeat this with the other instructions!");  
    }  
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);  
    sqlite3_close(_bdcontact);  
}
```

I have already done instructions like selects, inserts, updates and deletes in other parts of the application so the problem is when i try to do sqlite pure instructions.

Can You help me Please?

Comment: I do not think you can invoke these "dot" commands programmatically. If you check the result of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, I would wager you will not get `SQLITE_OK` (and you really should be checking that return code), and if not `SQLITE_OK`, you should `NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_bdcontact));` so you can see what the SQLite error message is.

Comment: Nope, you can't execute the "dot" commands. But it's easy enough to generate a CSV file from your data. Do a regular query. Convert each value to a string. If the string contains a comma or newline, wrap the value in double quotes. If the value contains a double quote, escape it with a backslash. Append the values with a comma between each value. Add a newline after each row.

Comment: I think that can´t be done :(

Thank you.